# Pass parameter from page to app.component from dark mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i use this git to enable dark mode to my project. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app

It works but i want to put the toggle button in a page and not to app.component.html

Dark theme works like that.

1. Toggle button in app.component.html

   ```
      <ion-app [class.dark-theme]="dark">
        <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
          <ion-item>
           <ion-icon slot="start" name="moon-outline"></ion-icon>
           <ion-label>
             Dark Mode
           </ion-label>
          <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="dark"></ion-toggle>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-split-pane>
      </ion-app>
   ```
2. Set dark parameter to false so it could change in toggle

   ```
        export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        dark = false;

         constructor(
   ```

So this works. And in case it works but only in the page not the whole project goes on dark only the page that i set the toggle. So i think that i have to pass parameter to app.component.ts?

I have added a new service Global Service

global.service.ts

```
   import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

    export class GlobalService {
       public darkModeToggleState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
       constructor(){}
     }
```

app.component.ts

```
      import { GlobalService } from './services/global.service/global.service';

      @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
       providers: [GlobalService],
      })
      export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      dark;
```

app.component.html that will change the class to dark

```
      <ion-app [class.dark-theme]="dark">
        <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
       </ion-app>
```

somepage.html

```
      <ion-toggle *ngIf="index === 5" [(ngModel)]="dark" (ionChange)="darkToggled($event)"></ion-toggle>
```

somepage.ts

```
       import { GlobalService } from '../../services/global.service/global.service';
        
     constructor(){}

      darkToggled(event){
        this.globalSrvc.darkModeToggleState.next(event.target.chacked)
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a BehaviourSubject to keep track of this toggle. Do it like this.

In your component html file

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="dark" (ionChange)="darkToggled($event)"></ion-toggle>
```

In your component .ts file

```
constructot(private globalSrvc:GlobalService){}
darkToggled(event){
   this.globalSrvc.darkModeToggleState.next(event.target.checked)
}
```

New service file, global.service.ts

```
export class GlobalService {
     public darkModeToggleState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
     constructor(){}
}
```

In your app.component.ts

```
dark;
constructor(private globalSrvc:GlobalService){
   this.globalSrvc.darkModeToggleState.subscribe(value=>{
       this.dark = value
   }
}
```

With this, you can add the dark mode toggle to multiple components, anywhere.

Comment: i have updated so i can show what i did. No errors but when change the toggle nothing happens

Comment: put breakpoint in you app.component.ts and see if `this.dark` value is updated when you toggle

Comment: you mean like this   this.globalSrvc.darkModeToggleState.subscribe(value=>{
      this.dark = value;
      console.log(value);
  }); returns false and when toggle returns undefined

Comment: Thanks man it works now. For future mention Chetan's answer works!!!